# save function calls in a container

Tags: c++, multithreading, opengl, c++11

I have several threads. One thread collects all the function calls that the user wants to execute. However, the functions need to be called from the other threads. So each of the other threads will have a queue of functions to call. Is there a way to implement this? Is it maybe possible with a std::vector< std::function< R(...)>>?

I want something like this:

The user calls functions like this:

```
createTriangle(ThreadID, Vec3, Vec3, Vec3)  
createSquare(ThreadID, Vec3, Vec3, Vec3, Vec3)
```

Now the main thread will send each function call to the right thread. Each thread will have a queue into which the main thread will push back the function and the arguments, maybe something like this:

```
q.emplace_back(createTriangle, a, b, c);  
q.emplace_back(createSquare, a, b, c, d);
```

Now, each thread will just iterate through the queue and call each given function with the corresponding arguments.

Is such a thing possible? I need something like this, because I use OpenGL and each OpenGL context has to create its own objects, it can't be created in another thread. (Or maybe it can, but that's rather difficult to handle I think.)

Comment: I can't help thinking that you should be pushing vectors of task objects on to a threadpool queue.

Comment: @Martin James: Could you elaborate? :-) I'm not sure if that what I asked for is what I exactly need.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can combine `std::function` with `std::bind` (or with lambdas) to do that. Something like this:

```
std::queue<std::function<void()>> q;

q.emplace_back(std::bind(createTriangle, a, b, c));
// or
q.emplace_back([=](){ createTriangle(a, b, c); });
```

Note that I used capture by value in the lambda, so that object lifetime is not an issue.

Comment: I forgot to ask, is std::queue thread-safe? I mean, can I emplace_back and pop_front at the same time?

Comment: @gartenriese No. Unless otherwise specified, `const` operations on `std` classes are thread-safe, non-`const` ones are not. You have to protect the queue yourself.